# FORM is not working when I use CKEditor in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I am using ckeditor in a form in cakephp application, editor is visible but form is unable to submit itself. Whereas it works fine in another page. I could not understand reason behind this.

Please find code below:

```
  <?php
   echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui');
   echo $this->Html->script('/ckeditor/ckeditor', false);
   ?>
   <div class="faqs form">
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('Faq'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Faq'); ?></legend>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('question');
    echo $this->Form->input('answer', array('class'=>'ckeditor'));
?>
</fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
    </div>
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: form end should in php tag.
<?php $this->From->end(_('Submit')) ; ?>
also from start 
<?php $this->Form->create(); ?>

Comment: thanks Alimon, code is not printed properly, so it seems like this. Submit button is in php tag. Please find code now.

Comment: Do you have a clear concept cakephp form making ?

Comment: Yes, I used multiple times. If there is any mistake, please suggest me.

Comment: @AmitJha Do you see the editor in your page? Maybe look at the javascript console to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Yes Holt, I can see editor.

Comment: Can you submit the form after removing validation of that field from the Model?

Comment: please read carefully form creation in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="faqs form">
   <?php echo $this->Form->create('Faq'); ?>
<fieldset>
    <legend><?php echo __('Add Faq'); ?></legend>
    <?php
    echo $this->Form->input('question');
    echo $this->Form->input('answer', array('class'=>'ckeditor'));
    ?>
</fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

Note1: Copy entire ckeditor into a folder in (webroot/js/ckeditor) and paste it here.

Note2: load the ckeditor at the end of your page

```
<?php echo echo $this->Html->script('ckeditor/ckeditor'); ?>
```

Comment: remove the jquery-ui.css for time being to see how your ckeditor works

Answer (score 0):

This could be the cause:

I think by default CakePHP treats all input as the type of 'text' you need to define that the input is a 'textarea'.

```
<?php
   echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui');
   echo $this->Html->script('/ckeditor/ckeditor', false);
?>
<div class="faqs form">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Faq'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?php echo __('Add Faq'); ?></legend>
            <?php
               echo $this->Form->input('question');
               echo $this->Form->input('answer', array('class'=>'ckeditor', 'type' => 'textarea'));
            ?>
        </fieldset>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>


// Or try this: (This mimics what you are trying to do)
<?php
   echo $this->Html->css('jquery-ui');
   echo $this->Html->script('/ckeditor/ckeditor', false);
?>
<div class="faqs form">
    <?php echo $this->Form->create('Faq'); ?>
        <fieldset>
            <legend><?php echo __('Add Faq'); ?></legend>
            <?php
               echo $this->Form->input('question');
               echo $this->Form->input('answer', array('class'=>'ckeditor', 'type' => 'textarea'));
            ?>
        </fieldset>
        <?php echo $this->Form->submit(__('Submit'), array('div' => false)); ?>
    <?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
</div>
```